# Is "oneself" a reflexive pronoun in the following example?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, reflexive-pronouns

***Pass the buck*** is an idiom meaning "to pass responsibility for a problem to another person to avoid dealing with it **oneself**."

Could you elaborate about this word and its meaning?

Comment: The form of the pronoun is known as the reflexive, but such forms can function either as a "true" reflexive or in an intensive/emphatic way.

Comment: Yes, "oneself" is a genuine reflexive pronoun. Reflexive pronouns have two uses: one where they function as complement and an emphatic use where they function as modifier in clause or NP structure. In your example "oneself" is obligatory and thus a complement. The antecedent of "oneself" (i.e. the subject of "dealing with it") is not not overtly stated, but is understood as referring to some arbitrary person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cited context, ***oneself*** isn't truly a "reflexive" pronoun - it's an ***intensive*** pronoun.

> 1: *The village barber shaves **himself***
> reflexive - the barber is both "agent" and "patient" (subject and object)

> 2: *The barber **himself** recommends this shampoo*
> emphasizes that *he personally* endorses it (and he's an expert on shampoo! :)

> 3a: *Can you answer the door? I don't have time to deal with it **myself***
> 3b: *Can you answer the door? I **myself** don't have time to deal with it*

Hopefully it's obvious that ***myself*** is functionally equivalent in both versions of #3. It should also be obvious that ***myself*** in #3 is the same "part of speech" as ***himself*** in #2 ("intensive, emphatic" pronoun), AND the same as ***oneself*** in OP's example.

---

I'm not 100% certain, but I have the impression the "intensive" sense is more common overall. And I further suspect that it's *always* "discardable". You don't *have* to be emphatic, so in principle any "non-reflexive" use of the pronoun can always be removed with no other syntactic implications.

Comment: Add? I already said that - *reflexive - the barber is both "agent" and "patient" (subject and object)*. Note that it's perfectly possible to include the same pronoun with both senses in the same sentence. *All the men in this village shave themselves - even the barber himself shaves himself*.

Comment: Oops!  I’ll delete my comment :-j

Comment: If "Oneself" is who passes resposibility, it is discardable and hard to translate to another language because there is no  pressent reference or atencedent of "oneself".

Comment: But in this case: He passed resposibility for a problem to another person to avoid dealing with it himself. We can include "himself" in translation

Comment: @KavehBehnia: I would have thought most languages would have some kind of adverbial element corresponding to ***personally***, which pretty much corresponds to the "emphatic" usage in most contexts. Idiomatically, the same basic idea is conveyed by *The **barber, no less,** recommends this shampoo*, or ***No less a person than** the barber recommends it*. But note that since OP's example is the emphatic usage, nothing really changes if it's omitted completely. It adds *nuance*, not "core meaning".